# Set the position of text in the center of button

Tags: android, user-interface, text, android-button

I have two buttons for zoom in and zoom out on my application. I want to put the "+ "and "-" in the center of button. I tried to set the gravity and padding but nothing changed and still the signs are located in the bottom of my button and half of it is not displayed. This is the xml code of layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/semanticText"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:background="@drawable/semantic_text_style"
        />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/zoom_button_style"
        android:id="@+id/zoomIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/zoom_in"
        android:onClick="zoomIn"
        style="@style/button_text"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/zoom_button_style"
        android:id="@+id/zoomOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zoom_out"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:onClick="zoomOut"
        style="@style/button_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would be thankful to give me a suggestion to solve it.

Comment: android:gravity="center" ?

Comment: I alos tried that, no change.

Answer (score 1):

You limited height of the layout to 50dp: `android:layout_height="50dp"`. Try to increase it or set to `wrap_content` and set `android:gravity="center"` for buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try android:gravity="center" not layout_gravity

Comment: android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
Try this

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton instead of Button  and

Don't use  android:background="@drawable/zoom_button_style" it set image in whole button rather use

```
android:src="@drawable/zoom_button_style"
```

and if you still not get that you want then use android:scaleType="centerCrop"